# Release visibility with Jenkins and Nexus

Tags: maven, jenkins, nexus

We use Maven, Jenkins and Nexus to build and deploy our software. The problem is that it's difficult for support and all of our people to know if a version is still in the QA staging repository, Beta or Release.

What tools are people using to make visibility of this possible? One option is to create a custom webapp that uses the nexus REST api to make it visible but I would imagine this is a solved problem and I shouldn't have to do that.

Any help or pointers in the right direction would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you use staging option of Nexus?

Comment: Yes we do. When Jenkins finishes a build the nexus maven staging plugin handles moving it into a staging repository called QA. We then take manual steps to promote to beta or Release.